# display a view content for a few seconds in a timeout function react native

Tags: react-native

I need to show the response or error message for some seconds how to do this using setTimeout function or by some other way. Any help is appreciated.

```
<View>
    {!!this.state.error && (
        <Text style={styles.message}>
          {this.state.errorMessage}
        </Text>
    )}
    {!!this.state.response && (
        <Text style={styles.successMessage}>
          {this.state.response}
        </Text>
    )}
</View>
```

This view either shows response message or an error message coming from the API.

Comment: The <View> is written inside the render function.

Answer (score 3):

When you want to trigger the error or response

```
this.setState({error: true},
  () => this.setTimeout(
     this.setState({error: false}), 5000
  )
)

                 OR

this.setState({error: true});
this.setTimeout(this.setState({error: false}), 5000);
```

Comment: I appreciate your response but since i am new to react native.. where am i supposed to write this function. Thanks in advance

Comment: I need to show either of the two depending on some condition for 5 seconds